# Is there a way for switch to return a string value using C# 8 switch expressions?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0, switch-expression

I have this code where each part of the switch returns a value to `ModeMessage2`. Is it possible using the new C# `switch` expressions (or any other code optimization) to optimize the way this `switch` works?

```cs
switch (Settings.Mode)
{
    case MO.Learn:
        ModeMessage2 =
            "Use this mode when you are first learning the phrases and their meanings.";
        if (Settings.Cc == CC.H)
        {
            Settings.Cc = CC.JLPT5;
            App.cardSetWithWordCount = null;
            App.DB.RemoveSelected();
        }
        break;
    case MO.Practice:
        ModeMessage2 =
             "Use this mode to help you memorize the phrases and their meanings.";
        if (Settings.Cc == CC.H)
        {
            Settings.Cc = CC.JLPT5;
            App.cardSetWithWordCount = null;
            App.DB.RemoveSelected();
        }
        break;
    case MO.Quiz:
        if (Settings.Cc == CC.H)
        {
            Settings.Cc = CC.JLPT5;
            App.cardSetWithWordCount = null;
            App.DB.RemoveSelected();
        }
        App.DB.UpdSet(SET.Adp, false);
        ModeMessage2 =
            "Use this mode to run a self marked test.";
        break;
}
```

Comment: A switch has no return value.  You return a string you need a string variable that is set in each case statement.  The string variable will be defined before the "switch" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is similar to the following, though if there are side effects of setting `ModeMessage2` or the other properties then the order that things happen might matter in which case this is not technically 100% equivalent.

```
IList<MO> specialModes = new[] { MO.Learn, MO.Practice, MO.Quiz };

if (specialModes.Contains(Settings.Mode) && Settings.Cc == CC.H) {
   Settings.Cc = CC.JLPT5;
   App.cardSetWithWordCount = null;
   App.DB.RemoveSelected();
}

ModeMessage2 = Settings.Mode switch {
   MO.Learn => "Use this mode when you are first learning the phrases and their meanings.",
   MO.Practice => "Use this mode to help you memorize the phrases and their meanings.",
   MO.Quiz => "Use this mode to run a self marked test.",
   _ => "Unknown mode value" // or throw
};

if (Settings.Mode == MO.Quiz)
   App.DB.UpdSet(SET.Adp, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var modeMessage2 = Settings.Mode switch
{
    MO.Learn => "Use this mode when you are first learning the phrases and their meanings.",
    MO.Practice => "Use this mode to help you memorize the phrases and their meanings.",
    MO.Quiz => "Use this mode to run a self marked test."
}

if (Settings.Cc == CC.H)
{
    Settings.Cc = CC.JLPT5;
    App.cardSetWithWordCount = null;
    App.DB.RemoveSelected();
}

if (Settings.Mode == MO.Quiz) {
    App.DB.UpdSet(SET.Adp, false);
}
```

Comment: The compiler will complain because this clause isn't exhaustive

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dictionary to do this --

```
 Dictionary<TypeOf(Settings.Mode), string> map = new Dictionary<TypeOf(Settings.Mode), string>();

 map.Add(MO.Learn,"Use this mode when you are first learning the phrases and their meanings.");
 map.Add(MO.Practice,"Use this mode to help you memorize the phrases and their meanings.");
 map.Add(MO.Quiz,"Use this mode to run a self marked test.");


 ModeMessage2 = map[Settings.mode]);
```

This will be much faster than any switch statement and easier to maintain.

You could also use an array if that makes sense.

---

Note to commenters below:  I'm making the following assumptions, which could be false in some cases but not in the general case.  1) the code is written in a way that the "allocation" only happens once for the lifetime of the code -- in this case if the map is used more than once, you get savings so that after N time the cost of allocation goes to 0.  2) We don't know the type of the key, comments that assume it is a string are making an assumption that might not be true. EVEN SO, any "fast" comparisons of strings is using a hash which is the same thing a dictionary uses to get it speed.  3) It is well known that the slowest thing you can do in programming is a branch.  A dictionary (or array map) allow you to not have any branches, just a calculation to a memory location.

Comment: Faster than direct comparisons?

Comment: "much faster than any switch statement"? I would think for three values that a dictionary would be a lot slower than a switch.

Comment: `This will be much faster than any switch statement`. It won't. For larger collection, sure the dictionary will be faster (Log(N) vs N). For `N = 3` there will be no noticeable difference

Comment: Allocating the dictionary and populating it will actually make it slower

Comment: Note that a switch statement is *incredibly* well optimized for strings. It starts off with a linear search for a small number of strings, then it moves onto embedding a hash function in your assembly and doing a tree search using the hash code, then finally it moves onto using a dictionary.